# Proving a tautology by using logical equivalences

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

I have to prove
$$(\lnot(a\land b) \land (b \lor c)\land(c\rightarrow d)) \Rightarrow (a \rightarrow d)$$
So far I have done this:

$$\lnot (a\land b)\land (b\lor c)\land (c\rightarrow d)$$
$$\iff (\lnot a \lor \lnot b) \land (b \lor c)\land (\lnot c \lor d)$$
$$\iff (\lnot a \land (b\lor c))\lor(\lnot b \land (b\lor c))\land (\lnot c \lor d)$$
$$\iff ((b\lor c)\land \lnot a)\lor ((b\lor c)\land \lnot b))\land (\lnot c\lor d)$$

I don't know what can I do next or different

Comment: You can take a big shortcut from your second line by considering the [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) argument if you'd like

Comment: You have both a $\to$ and a $\Rightarrow$ … is the latter meant as a logical implication? If so, what is it that you are trying to prove to be a tautology? I am confused … can you be more clear please?